# Get user home directories recursively in PowerShell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

So, I'm taking the dive into PowerShell. I've been tasked with redoing permissions on every home folder in the domain (they do not all fall under the same sub-directory - that would be too easy). I have a batch script written that takes two parameters: user name, and home folder path and pumps them through SetACL.

I want to use PowerShell to get the user names and home folders for every user in an OU. So far, I can get the user names, but I cannot figure out how to get the home directories.

This is my PowerShell so far (borrowed from various sources across the web):

```
$Dom = "LDAP://OU=Accounts,DC=myDomain,DC=local"
$Root = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $Dom

# Create a selector and start searching from the Root of AD
$selector = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$selector.SearchRoot = $root
$Selector.pagesize = 20000


# Basically this will only grab user accounts and not computer accounts.
$adobj= $selector.findall() | where {
    $_.properties.objectcategory -match "CN=Person*"
}
foreach ($person in $adobj) {
    $prop=$person.properties
    Write-host "$($prop.cn)"
}
```

I'm eventually going to pipe the Write-host line into the setACL batch file, but I'm just writing the output for now to make sure that it's accurate. I've tried adding`$($prop.homeDirectory)` to the Write-host line with no luck.

Any pointers or suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has updated their Active Directory powershell module and it is included with RSAT.  Should you not want to use a third-party's modules, the following lists the `sAMAaccountName` and `homeDirectory` attributes for all users in the "JustAnOrgUnit" OU -- pretty much the same as @nimizen's answer, just without the Quest requirement.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=JustAnOrgUnit,DC=example,DC=com" -Filter * -Property * |
    Select-Object -Property sAMAccountName,homeDirectory |
        Export-CSV -Path C:\somefile.csv
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of native tools over 3rd party tools whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use Quest's AD cmdlets, they're free and really simplify this sort of thing.

You can get them from http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx

Once you have those loaded, try the following script but also have a read around the Get-QADUser cmdlet.

```
$csvfile = "C:\somefile.csv"
$root = "OU=Accounts,DC=myDomain,DC=local"
get-qaduser -SearchRoot $root `
-ObjectAttributes @{homeDirectory=’*'} -IncludeAllProperties | `
Select-Object LogonName,HomeDirectory | `
Export-Csv $csvfile
```

Comment: +1, this seems to be working well. I'm going to run it against the 20k object OU that I want with the -SizeLimit set to 0 and see what I get. I'd still like to know what I was doing wrong above though, any idea?

Comment: No need to use -IncludeAllProperties, HomeDirectory is returned in the default output of Get-QADUser. You also need to specify '-SizeLimit 0' to be able to bypass the default 1000 objects limitation.

Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 0 -SearchRoot "OU=Accounts,DC=myDomain,DC=local" -HomeDirectory * | Select-Object LogonName,HomeDirectory | Export-Csv C:\somefile.csv
  
Mark, add these lines to your script:
$selector.Filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(HomeDirectory=*))"
$selector.findall() | foreach {$_.properties.homedirectory)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to update it on each homeDirectory without using multiple tools, and run through each account on-by-on from an OrgUnit and recursively go through each subOU too.

```perl
# source ACL required
$NewAcl = Get-Acl -Path "C:\directory\as\template"

# load active directory powershell module (requires RSAT installed)
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory -Force

# get all AD Users in OU from example, then set new Acl from source directory on their home directory paths
Get-ADuser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Accounts,DC=myDomain,DC=local" -Properties homeDirectory | ForEach-Object {
    $homedir = $_.'homeDirectory'
    try {
        # set acl settings
        Set-Acl -Path $homedir -AclObject $NewAcl -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
        # write output to console if successful
        Write-Output "Successfully updated ACL settings for ${homedir}"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "Unable to update ACL settings on ${homedir}"
    }
}
```